# Prestashop 1.7 Error chose attribute in product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

When selecting an attribute in the product, Prestashop show me this error

[image]

I have Prestashop 1.7.7.2, before two days working in this error, the solution is very simply

Disabled the module ps_viewedproduct in Spanish into the product is this screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is the attribute id_product when you select "Add to cart" in this screen, is the same to the attribute to the main form of the product.

[image]
I hope help you this solution :)